# Several group_concat in the same query

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join, group-concat

I have one main table (m) in MySQL and two auxiliaries (a,b).

I have this query:

```
SELECT *,group_concat(a.name_auxone) as namesone
FROM main m 
    LEFT JOIN auxiliaryone a ON m.id_main=a.id_main_auxone 
    WHERE m.id_main=1
```

... and after creating with php $row[], it displays:

```
$row['namesone']-->name1,name2,name3
```

This is ok (I have 3 registers in auxiliarione associated to the id_main=1). But if I want to join the other auxiliary table (with 2 registers associated to id_main=1) with this query...

```
SELECT *,group_concat(a.name_auxone) as namesone,
         group_concat(b.name_auxtwo) as namestwo 
FROM main m 
    LEFT JOIN auxiliaryone a ON m.id_main=a.id_main_auxone 
    LEFT JOIN auxiliarytwo b ON m.id_main=b.id_main_auxtwo
```

... I have this values:

```
$row['namesone']-->nameone1,nameone1,   nameone2,nameone2,   nameone3,nameone3
$row['namestwo']-->nametwo1,nametwo2,   nametwo1,nametwo2,   nametwo1,nametwo2
```

So.. 
in namesone (3 registers associated), each register is repeated 2 times.
in namestwo (2 registers associated), the 2 registers are repeated 3 times.
I put the spaces between the groups of registers, to see clearly how they are repeated (11,22,33  and  12,12,12).

The correct display should be:

```
$row['namesone']-->nameone1,nameone2,nameone3
$row['namestwo']-->nametwo1,nametwo2
```

(123   and  12) What am i doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: It will be helpful if you create a sqlfiddle.com url with sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that using `DISTINCT`. Try this:

```
SELECT *,group_concat(DISTINCT a.name_auxone) as namesone,
     group_concat(DISTINCT b.name_auxtwo) as namestwo 
FROM main m 
LEFT JOIN auxiliaryone a ON m.id_main=a.id_main_auxone 
LEFT JOIN auxiliarytwo b ON m.id_main=b.id_main_auxtwo
```